# PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ::(url)()

Tags: php

Whats wrong with my codes, I always got fatal error when I change my URL. I can't remove those if else below which have undefined, I will not get 2nd URL. I am beginner creating MVC please help

```
class event_trap
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        $url = rtrim($url. '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        //print_r($url);

        $file = 'event_mvc/controllers/' .$url[0] . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        } else {
            require 'event_mvc/controllers/error.php';
            $controller = new Error();
            return false;
        }

        $controller = new $url[0]; 

        if (isset($url[2])) {
            $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]); //<-- Undefined method
        } else {
            if(isset($url[1])) {
                $controller -> {$url[1]}(); //<-- Undefined method
            } else {

            }     
        }
    }
}
```

var_dump($url)

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'event' (length=5)
  1 => string '' (length=0)

Fatal error: Call to undefined method event::() in 
   C:\wamp\www\tabulation\event_mvc\libs\Bootstrap.php on line 33
  Call Stack
   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location
   1    0.0004  142728  {main}( )   ..\event.php:0 
   2    0.0012  149096  event_trap->__construct( )  ..\event.php:4
```

Comment: Please show your invocation of the object, and your query string.

Comment: Please `var_dump($url)`.

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag var_dump() shows me array (size=2)
  0 => string 'event' (length=5)
  1 => string '' (length=0), and the error is Fatal error: Call to undefined method event::(), that is when i remove the $ur[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$url` is an array which you use to create an object and call methods with or without parameters. With the array ou have var_dumped 0=>event, 1=>'' you are creating an object of class event and call the method '' which does not exist. Correct your code or pass a valid function name.

You can try this which checks for empty string too.

```
if (isset($url[2]) && !empty($url[2]) {
    $controller->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
} else {
    if(isset($url[1]) && !empty($url[1]) {
        $controller -> {$url[1]}();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, also that dumping url really helpful

Comment: I consider you check for function first and parameter after that. You can also use `method_exists()` to check for existence of methods, if you are using variable function calls.